# Joining lines that matches specific conditions in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I need a command that will join lines if:
-following line starts with more than 5 spaces
-length of the joined lines won't be greater than 79 characters
-those lines are not between lines with pattern1 and pattern2
-same as above but with another set of patterns, like pattern3 and pattern4

It will work on a file like this:

> ```
> Long line that contains too much text for combining it with following one  
> That line cannot be attached to the previous becouse of the length
> This one also 
> becouse it doesn't start with spaces
>
> This one 
>      could be
>      expanded
>
> pattern1
> here are lines
>      that shouldn't be 
>      changed
> pattern2
>
> Another line
>      to grow
> ```

After running the command, output should be:

> ```
> Long line that contains too much text for combining it with following one  
> That line cannot be attached to the previous becouse of the length
> This one also 
> becouse that one doesn't start with spaces
>
> This one could be expanded
>
> pattern1
> here are lines
>      that shouldn't be 
>      changed
> pattern2
>
> Another line to grow
> ```

It can't move part of the line.

I'm using bash 2.05 sed 3.02 awk 3.1.1 and grep 2.5.1 and i don't know how to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        TRUE = printflag1 = printflag2 = 1
        FALSE = 0
}

# using two different flags prevents premature enabling when blocks are
# nested or intermingled
/pattern1/ {
        printflag1 = FALSE
}

/pattern2/ {
        printflag1 = TRUE
}
/pattern3/ {
        printflag2 = FALSE
}

/pattern4/ {
        printflag2 = TRUE
}

{
        line = $0
        sub(/^ +/, " ", line)
        sub(/ +$/, "", line)
}

/^     / &&
    length(accum line) <= 79 &&
    printflag1 &&
    printflag2 {
        accum = accum line
        next
}

{
        print accum
        accum = line
}
```